# Install SSH Module Pear

Tags: php, pear, phpseclib

How to install module `crypt_random_string`, `Crypt_Hash`, and `Crypt_Base` with php pear?

I tried to use `pear list-all` but there's no module from that module.
And I tried using the following commands

```
pear install phpseclib/crypt_random_string
pear install phpseclib/Crypt_Hash
pear install phpseclib/Crypt_Base
```

but it's giving me the following error `install failed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow:

```
pear channel-discover phpseclib.sourceforge.net
pear remote-list -c phpseclib
pear install phpseclib/Crypt_Random
pear install phpseclib/Crypt_Hash
pear install phpseclib/Crypt_Base
```

Also provide us pear version, OS